# Do all variables in a serialized class become part of the serialization process in Java?

Tags: java, variables, serialization

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk99T.pngstrong text

In addition, does it matter whether the variables being part of the serialization process are instance variables or variables in conductors in methods or object variables?

Comment: Static members are [not serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429462/java-static-serialization-rules). But otherwise: if you serialize an object, then all of its non-static fields are serialized as well, and if they refer to objects then that applies recursively. And everything has to be `Serializable` otherwise you will get an exception when you try to serialize the object.

Comment: Also, please [post code as text, not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Also, `transient` fields are ignored during serialization. At least by default. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html#defining-serializable-fields-for-a-class

Comment: And here's the full spec: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/serialization/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization with the marker interface you mentioned is a tough topic in Java. All member fields of an object will get serialized, except the ones marked with the keyword `transient`. Other variables like local variables or parameters to constructors or methods are not serialized.

It is easy to corrupt a Java program by deserializing malicious or corrupted data. You can customize, what will be serialized by implementing the methods `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s)` and `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s)`

As you can see, those private (!) methods are not members of the interface `Serializable`, so it's compiler magic that calls them for serialization. If you do not implement them, there is a default implementation.

Don't forget to specify the variable

`private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` and give it a new value for each update of your member fields - this will prevent that you deserialize data from another version of your class where the data does not suite the implementation.

In general: If you really have to use serialization, I would recommend that you read more articles on it, e.g. https://ahdak.github.io/blog/effective-java-part-11/ - it summarizes from the book "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch.

Also the [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) could be interesting for you.